CMIP6, automating by month
Thanks in advance for any help and insight. I am still new/learning R.
I am working with CMIP6 historical data across several models for several variables. Ideally, my baseline would run from 1850 - 1950. In this example, I have monthly temperature data for 2 different climate models, I'd like to work across 6 models. Both models use "days since 1850 01 01" to account for time at 29.5 day increments. Once I create an array, I can slice data out at 1, 13, 25, etc. to represent a given month/year.
I would like to extract data as an average across each historical time period for each month. So one data layer/file per month averaged across 100 years. I have code worked out to extract a single month, for a single year, for a single model, but this would be brutal for a baseline from 1850 - 1950, or even 1900 - 1950. (100 years * 12 months * 6 models = 72,000 rows of code).
Is there a for loop or other more elegant/simple approach to make this feasible?  When I say I am a newb to R, I would be unablenot sure how to write a forfor loop using this data structure.
I would prefer to avoid reducing the number of years and number of models to make this a feasible lift. I could copy and paste and manually adjust, but this would be very time consuming, and I know the more experienced coders are shaking their heads/laughing at me:).
I am using the following (brutally simple unelegant) code:
library(raster)
library(RNetCDF)
library(ncdf4)

####open .nc file for each model, variable, and time period###

nc_data <- nc_open('tas_Amon_GFDL-CM4_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr1_185001-194912.nc')
nc_data2 <- nc_open('tas_Amon_GISS-E2-1-G_historical_r101i1p1f1_gn_185001-194912.nc')

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lon_bnds")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lat_bnds")
t <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time_bnds")

lon2 <- ncvar_get(nc_data2, "lon_bnds")
lat2 <- ncvar_get(nc_data2, "lat_bnds")
t2 <- ncvar_get(nc_data2, "time_bnds")

head(t)
nc_data$dim ###QA/QC: lat len 180; lon len 288; time len 1200; note time $vals starts at 15.5,then increases by 29.5 thereafter, e.g. 15.5, 45.0, 74.5 etc###

tas.arrayGFDL <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "tas") ###store the data in a 3-dimensional array###
dim(tas.arrayGFDL) ###QA/QC matches the length given nc_data$dim)###

tas.jan1850GFDL <- tas.arrayGFDL[, , 1] ###first slice is jan 1850###
dim(tas.jan1850GFDL) ##correct lat, lon##

tas.jan1851GFDL <- tas.arrayGFDL[, , 13] ###13th slice is jan 1851###
dim(tas.jan1851GFDL) ##correct lat, lon##

tas.jan1850rGFDL<- raster(t(tas.jan1850GFDL), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
tas.jan1851rGFDL<- raster(t(tas.jan1850GFDL), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))

plot(tas.jan1850rGFDL)


plot(tas.jan1851rGFDL)

tas.jan1850rfGFDL <- flip(tas.jan1850rGFDL, direction='y')
tas.jan1851rfGFDL <- flip(tas.jan1851rGFDL, direction='y')

plot(tas.jan1850rfGFDL)


plot(tas.jan1851rfGFDL)

writeRaster(tas.jan1850rfGFDL, "tas.jan1850rfGFDL.tif", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

writeRaster(tas.jan1851rfGFDL, "tas.jan1851rfGFDL.tif", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

Then repeat for each month, each year, each model.

If it is possible, using the URLs for the NCDF files, instead of the local file names, would allow others to run your code and try out solutions - i.e., it would make your code a minimal reproducible example.

With package ncdfCF you get a more intelligent solution for netCDF files that follow the CF Metadata Conventions (CF), as all CMIP6 files do (among very many other data sets). It is pure R code, no need for external libraries.
Step-by-step
For a single file it works like in the blocks of code below. This is the step-by-step version so that you see and learn what is going on. The compact version for multiple models and variables is further down.
package(ncdfCF)
package(CFtime)

ds <- open_ncdf("GFDL_file.nc")
ds
#> <Dataset> ts_Amon_GFDL-ESM4_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr1_18500116-19491216 
#> Resource   : ~/ts_Amon_GFDL-ESM4_historical_r1i1p1f1_gr1_18500116-19491216.nc 
#> Format     : netcdf4 
#> Conventions: CF-1.7 CMIP-6.0 UGRID-1.0 
#> Keep open  : FALSE 
#> Has groups : FALSE 
#> 
#> Variable:
#>  name long_name           units data_type axes          
#>  ts   Surface Temperature K     NC_FLOAT  lon, lat, time
#> 
#> Axes:
#>  id axis name long_name     length unlim values                                        unit
#>  0  T    time               1200   U     [1850-01-16 12:00:00 ... 1949-12-16 12:00:00] days since 1850-01-01
#>  1       bnds vertex number    2         [1 ... 2]                                    
#>  2  Y    lat  latitude       180         [-89.5 ... 89.5]                              degrees_north
#>  3  X    lon  longitude      288         [0.625 ... 359.375]                           degrees_east
#> 
#> Attributes:
#> (omitted for brevity)

First of all, the file is slightly different than yours, it is GFDL-ESM4 with variable "ts", but that should not make any difference. Some other interesting details:

The file follows the CF-1.7 metadata conventions. Just the way we like it.
The file has only a single data variable, ts in this case. CMIP6 files always have only a single data variable, but not every netCDF package will limit itself to just the data variables. You can also find the name with names(ds). The variable has 3 axes, lon, lat and time, and we indeed see them in the list of axes (the bnds "axis" is not actually and axis, we can forget about that one).

Getting the data variable is easy. But that still doesn't get you the actual data, you need to explicitly ask for it (the reason being that you might want to subset to a specific area or time period before doing the actual reading of any data from file).
# Get the data variable `ts`
ts <- ds[["ts"]]

# Read the actual data from file into a "CFData" object
d <- ts$data()
d
#> <Data> ts 
#> Long name: Surface Temperature 
#> 
#> Values: [192.6449 ... 320.3623] K
#>     NA: 0 (0.0%)
#> 
#> Axes:
#>  id axis name long_name length unlim values                                        unit                 
#>  3  X    lon  longitude  288         [0.625 ... 359.375]                           degrees_east         
#>  2  Y    lat  latitude   180         [-89.5 ... 89.5]                              degrees_north        
#>  0  T    time           1200   U     [1850-01-16 12:00:00 ... 1949-12-16 12:00:00] days since 1850-01-01
#> 
#> Attributes:
#> (omitted)

# Now get the data into an R array
arr <- d$array()
str(arr)
#>  num [1:180, 1:288, 1:1200] 241 241 241 241 242 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#>   ..$ lat : chr [1:180] "89.5" "88.5" "87.5" "86.5" ...
#>   ..$ lon : chr [1:288] "0.625" "1.875" "3.125" "4.375" ...
#>   ..$ time: chr [1:1200] "1850-01-16 12:00:00" "1850-02-15 00:00:00" "1850-03-16 12:00:00" "1850-04-16 00:00:00" ...

This array is oriented in the regular R way, so-called "column-major order". So the first dimension is decreasing latitude, then longitude, then time as 1,200 months. Turning this into monthly averages is done using a factor, from base R. Here, however, I am using package CFtime to create the factor because that is better suited to working with climate projection data.
So let's look at the "time" dimension:
t <- d$axes[["time"]]
t
#> <Time axis> [0] time
#> Length   : 1200 (unlimited)
#> Axis     : T 
#> Range    : 1850-01-16 12:00:00 ... 1949-12-16 12:00:00 (days) 
#> Bounds   : 1850-01-01 ... 1950-01-01 
#> 
#> Attributes:
#>  id name          type    length value                
#>  0  long_name     NC_CHAR  4     time                 
#>  1  axis          NC_CHAR  1     T                    
#>  2  calendar_type NC_CHAR  6     noleap               
#>  3  bounds        NC_CHAR  9     time_bnds            
#>  4  standard_name NC_CHAR  4     time                 
#>  5  description   NC_CHAR 13     Temporal mean        
#>  6  units         NC_CHAR 21     days since 1850-01-01
#>  7  calendar      NC_CHAR  6     noleap

Again some insights:

The "time" axis uses bounds and they are automatically generated (so no need to fiddle with the "time_bnds" "variable", as ncdf4 calls it, but according to CF, the bounds of a data variable are metadata, not a separate variable).
The calendar is "noleap", meaning that no year has a leap day. This means that you cannot use simple date operations in R. Package CFtime is specifically designed to deal with the vagaries of the various types of "model time" defined by CF. Note that other models may use other calendars.

You can get your hands on the CFtime object and then create a factor for monthly data over the period 1850-1949:
cft <- t$values
fac <- CFfactor(cft, epoch = 1850:1949)

In the final step you can calculate the monthly means over the entire period with straight R:
# Read the below as: apply over the first 2 dimensions, latitude and longitude,
# the function tapply(), which applies the mean() function using the factor
# over the third dimension, time.
res <- apply(arr, 1:2, tapply, fac, mean)

# tapply() changes the axis order, so change back
res <- aperm(res, c(2, 3, 1))
str(res)
#>  num [1:180, 1:288, 1:12] 240 240 240 241 242 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#>   ..$ lat: chr [1:180] "89.5" "88.5" "87.5" "86.5" ...
#>   ..$ lon: chr [1:288] "0.625" "1.875" "3.125" "4.375" ...
#>   ..$    : chr [1:12] "01" "02" "03" "04" ...

Now you can further process the array as you please.
Easy! That's 12,000 lines of your code done.
In a function
Putting it all in a function is probably the best way to code once, run often. You can then also add further processing or other tweaks to simplify your analysis.
processCMIP6model <- function(fn) {
  ds <- open_ncdf(fn)
  var <- ds[[names(ds)]]
  d <- var$data()
  arr <- d$array()
  t <- d$axes[["time"]]$values
  fac <- CFfactor(t, epoch = 1850:1949)
  aperm(apply(arr, 1:2, tapply, fac, mean), c(2, 3, 1))
}

Assuming your 6 CMIP6 models are in a single directory you can do it all in one sweep:
lf <- list.files("~/CMIP6/data/directory", ".nc$", full.names = TRUE)
res <- lapply(lf, processCMIP6model)
names(res) <- basename(lf)

res is a list with one element for each of the files in your directory. Note that you can do this with as many CMIP6 files as you have, mixing variables as you go.
Plotting and other analyses
You can easily plot the resulting list using the terra package (which is the successor to the raster package):
# Starting with the list of model results from above
model1r <- terra::rast(res[[1]])

# Optionally, set layer names
names(model1r) <- month.abb
model1r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 288, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 288, 0, 180  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> source(s)   : memory
#> names       :      Jan,      Feb,      Mar,      Apr,      May,      Jun, ... 
#> min values  : 228.2004, 221.2835, 208.5045, 202.0122, 200.8219, 200.0914, ... 
#> max values  : 313.0564, 310.6226, 311.3170, 311.8899, 313.6404, 317.6213, ... 

plot(model1r, "Jan")


Other kinds of analysis can similarly be done directly using the array in the res list.
72,000 lines of code done.

Thanks so much Patrick! I followed along in the step by step, and at first wasn't sure how to plot 'res', then I figured out I needed to slice out a given month.
res.jan <- res[, , 1]                                                                                                                                                       Then I could convert to a raster format and plot the data. However, I had to change the order of the lat, lon (3, 2, 1 rather than 2, 3, 1). Then everything plotted correctly. Thank you again so much!

In case others read this: When I reran the code there was a bug and things wouldn't plot correctly. Rather than changing the order of the lat lon as I wrote above, then converting to a raster, I realized I could transpose: resr.jantranspose<-t(resr.jan)
plot(resr.jantranspose). That seemed to do the trick. Patrick, very grateful for your help, thank you.

I do not get the same error that you have. Please see my further explanation at the end of my answer.

You are amazing, thank you, the last bit was fantastic. I am trying to save the output as a tiff file. When I write:
writeRaster(model1r, "uni_18501949.jan.tif", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
Error: [write] unknown option(s):                                                                                                       Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Thanks for the praise! The final error is because in library terra you do not use the format = "GTiff" argument like before with library raster. So writeRaster(model1r, "uni_18501949.jan.tif", overwrite=TRUE) should work.

It looks like the package processNC does roughly what you are looking for:

Overview processNC is an R package for processing and analysing NetCDF files in R. NetCDF files can easily be loaded into R using the rast() function from the terra package in R or formerly also using the raster() function from the raster package. However, when trying to handle large NetCDF files it might be more convenient to directly use the ncdf4 package or the Climate Data Operators software and this package provides a simplified wrapper for those two options.The need for this package arised from the task to load large NetCDF files with global daily climate data to calculate monthly or yearly averages. With this package this task can be achieved in a much faster way and without having to read the entire file into memory.

Specifically, one of the examples included on the home page is for how to summarize by month over many years:

# Summarise daily NetCDF file for 10 years first by month and then by year
s <- summariseNC(files=tas_files[4], startdate=2001, enddate=2010,
                 group_col=c("month", "year"))
s

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 15, 18, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : 6, 15, 47.5, 55  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
names       : January, February,  March,  April,    May,   June, ... 
min values  :  269.81,   271.11, 274.13, 278.36, 283.22, 286.39, ... 
max values  :  276.14,   277.16, 280.17, 284.59, 288.88, 292.26, ... 


You'll still need do this for each model. I'd suggest taking a little time to learn how to use R's iteration tools: either purrr::map (tutorial) or base R's lapply. Doing it this way, rather than copy-and-pasting, is not only beneficial due to the saved time (which wouldn't be that much for only six models), but also because it ensures that you are performing the processing the exact same way for each model.
